# Query COUNT(field) doesnt take id in consideration

Tags: mysql, sql, count, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I have the following query:

```
         SELECT     dtr_user.username, 
                    dtr_user.loggedin, 
                    dtr_user.profilepicture, 
                    dtr_siterank.siterankname, 
                    dtr_user.joindate, 
                    COUNT(forum_post.postid), 
                    COUNT(dtr_entries.entreeid) 
            FROM    dtr_user, 
                    forum_post, 
                    dtr_entries, 
                    dtr_siterank 
            WHERE dtr_user.userid = ? 
            AND dtr_user.userid = dtr_entries.entreeauthor
            AND dtr_user.userid = forum_post.userid
            AND dtr_user.siterank = dtr_siterank.siterankid
```

So i expected it for me to return the count of postid.s of the poster, and same with count of the entree id's

When i run `SELECT COUNT(forum_post.postid) FROM forum_post where forum_post.userid = 1` it returns the correct number(17), same with `SELECT COUNT(dtr_entries.entreeid) FROM dtr_entries where dtr_entries.entreeauthor = 1` which returns `4`

Yet in the main query it comes to a `68` on both numbers. Do I apply a left join on this? Queries have not been my string suit really.

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and make a [mre]

Comment: The count is being multiplied because the joins return 4 rows for each post.

Comment: Perhaps you mean to be doing `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`?

COUNT() without distinct just counts the number of times the argument is not null, which is why your two ids are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT  u.*, s.siterankname, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM forum_post fp WHERE fp.user_id = u.userid) cnt_forum_post,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dtr_entries e WHERE e.entreeauthor = u.user_id) cnt_dtr_entries
FROM dtr_user u
INNER JOIN dtr_siterank s ON s.siterankid = u.siterank
WHERE u.userid = ?
```

Rationale:

- your original code is not a valid aggregation query; you need a `GROUP BY` clause, that should be consistent with the `SELECT` clause
- but even so, the results would be wrong if you have several matches per user in both the `forum_post` and `dtr_entries` tables; to avoid that, I used to correlated subqueries to count the number of matching entries in each of the two tables (which avoids the need for outer aggregation)
- I assumed that there is only one match in `dtr_siterank`, and used a regular join to bring the column `siterankname`

Notes:

- don't use implicit joins! This old syntax (with commas in the `FROM` clause) fell out of favor decades ago when explicit joins (with the `JOIN ... ON` keywords) became the standard
- table aliases make the queries easier to write and read

Comment: thanks for the explanation. and yes. you are correct, there can only be one result in siterank. Thanks for the pointers! I will use them definitely